# Grabbing specific files in a folder

Tags: java

I am attempting to grab all of the mkv files in a folder and place their names in an array, yet my code only returns one value for some reason.  I thought the FilenameFilter() would return all appropriate values, not just the first entry it encounters.

```
//Get a list of all mkv files in the extraction folder
File file = new File(extractedFolder);
File[] listoffiles = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mkv");
        }
});
```

Do I need to iterate through this code?  Is my array only setup to handle one entry?  Those are the only two potential problems I can see with this code, but both seem fine to my eye.

[Java: Find .txt files in specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384947/java-find-txt-files-in-specified-folder) is a resource I was using as well.

**EDIT:** My filestructure has everything sitting in the same folder.  That folder address is

```
C:\Users\user1\Documents\folder1\extraction files.
```

Inside the "extraction files" folder, are  27 mkv files and 28 xml files (see image).  The code I gave above only is pulling 12 files at a time.  Do I need to specify a number when I initially create the array?

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Using this resource ([Java process - unable to unzip zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653982/java-process-unable-to-unzip-zip-file)), I realized that a buffer I was using to unzip files (before grabbing them with the code above) was filling up and killing the process.  Essentially, the issue was using a Runtime() instead of a ProcessBuilder() (which can prevent cmd from buffer overflows).  Problem solved!

Comment: This should work. Could be problem with your files. Can you just loop through and check if result is different.

Comment: Agree that this seems correct. Perhaps the directory only contains one `.mkv` file. Seems like you really need to add a breakpoint and see what directory `extractedFolder` refers to.

Comment: Just tested your code myself. Works correctly for me.

Comment: try to accept all files and check whether it actually list all files you expect

Comment: Are all your MKV files present within the top level **extracted** folder? Or is that the top level folder has a single file and then the remaining files may be within sub-folders of the extracted folder? In that case, you may want to recurse through the directory to get all the required mkv files

Comment: can you show/print  your directory structure?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `FilenameFilter` to simply `return true;`?

Comment: I have not attempted that.  With xml files in the folder as well, wouldn't this cause it to pull in all the xml files as well?  In any case, I did a clean and build and the code started working again.  I'll test it over the next few days to see if it continues to work.

Comment: The code above is only pulling 12 mkv files at a time.  Is the initial size of an array defaulted to 12 or something?

Comment: Make sure all files indeed have .mkv extension and non of them is hidden or write only. BTW, are these really files created in 31/12/1979?

Comment: This particular batch came from a camera that hasn't had the proper date set on it yet.  None of the MKV's are hidden or read only.  :/

Comment: Additionally, the file structure is C:\Users\User1\Documents\Folder1\mkv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use FileUtils in [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to handle this for you.

Use the following method: [http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File, java.lang.String[], boolean](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

I've cut-n-pasted my file scanning code below.  I don't see whats wrong with your version, but hopefully this will help.  This way is a little different, and will hopefully work in your system.

```
    // FYI, m_dir is of type Path
    File dir = m_dir.toFile();

    if(dir.isDirectory())
    {
        for(File f : dir.listFiles())
        {
            // you probably want to replace the 2 lines below
            // with a check for .mkv files + processing
            logger.debug("File " + f.getName() + " found during inital search");
            m_listener.fileFoundInitialScan(f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I did a clean and build and the code started working miraculously (which makes no sense, since I thought I did this several days ago).  I'll definitely try this if problems crop up again.