# Unzip file with ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java

I modified some of the suggestions I found in this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653982/java-process-unable-to-unzip-zip-file) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621838/createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) to get the code snippet below, the challenge is that it runs without error, but does not extract the content of the `release.zip`, any pointers to what I am missing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        /* Unzip the release */
        File folder = new File("./input/");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe",
                "x",
                "./input/matsimInput/release.zip",
                "new");
        pb.directory(folder);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process pbProcess = null;
        int pbExitCode = 1;

            pbProcess = pb.start();
            pbExitCode = pbProcess.waitFor();

        if(pbExitCode != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not unzip release for MATSim run");
        }

    }
```

Comment: My I suggestion to use the built-in zipping algorithm instead. Invoking an external application is kinda crazy. Search for 'Java GZIP' or smth along the lines of that.

Comment: +1 to use the Java ZIP / GZIP native capabilities to extract data from ZIP-archives. Otherwise you owe us an explanation why do you want to use external application and make your code platform (Windows) dependent?

Comment: Google gives a nice article as one of the first hits, just for you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress

Comment: Since you're not actually reading the output of the process, how do you know if it's actually failing or not?

Answer (score 0):

Using 7-zip is one option. If you have java installed, you can use jar also.
An example to modify the process builder command:
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/C", "jar", "-xf" "");

Here: -x means extraction and -f refers to the filename. 
This will extract the file in the current directory where you have your java program.